# How to disable EXTI interrupt under stm32 MCUs with SPL library?

Tags: stm32

I need to disable EXTI interrupt under stm32 with SPL. Here is my configuration:

```
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOStruc;
EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStruct;

RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA,ENABLE);

GPIOStruc.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_IPU;
GPIOStruc.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_4;
GPIOStruc.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&GPIOStruc);

GPIO_EXTILineConfig(GPIO_PortSourceGPIOA,GPIO_PinSource4);

EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Line=EXTI_Line4;
EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;
EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;
EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Rising_Falling;
EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStruct);    

NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_2); 
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel =EXTI4_IRQn ;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority =2;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 2;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
```

I need to disable the above EXTI.

Comment: Did you try something like `NVIC_DisableIRQ(EXTI4_IRQn);`?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

As Brhans said by using the NVIC_DisableIRQ the EXTI can be disabled.